# Javascript form validation no alert on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, onsubmit

I am trying to validate my form before submitting it but the form is being submitted anyway without any alerts coming up, even though the form is being submitted blank. When the submit button is clicked I want to make sure information has been completed and is correct, and when it is blank or incorrect an alert should come up without submitting the form.

Thanks

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Oaktown Football Club</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="formValidation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Oaktown Football Club Logo"/>
    <h1>Oaktown Football Club</h1>
<nav>
<a href="Index.html">Homepage</a>
<a href="Competitions.html">Competitions</a>
<a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
</header>
<section>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
<article>
    <h3>Secretary</h3>
    <p>Name: Laci Tanner</p>
    <p>Phone: (02) 6620 3324</p>
    <p>Email: <a href="mailto:secretary@oaktownfa.com.au">secretary@oaktownfa.com.au</a></p>
<h3>Leave us a message</h3>
<form method="post" action="actionPage.html" name="contactForm" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
<label>Full Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" size="35" name="fullName" id="name"><br>
<br><label>Email:</label><br>
<input type="text" size="35" name="email" id="email"><br>
<br><label>Phone:</label><br>
<input type="text" size="35" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
<br><label>Team:</label><br>
<select name="team"><br>
<option>Please Choose</option>
<option>Adults</option>
<option>Under 12s</option>
<option>Under 6s</option>
</select><br>
<br><label>I am:</label><br>
<select name="Member"><br>
<option>Please Choose</option>
<option>Thinking about joining the club</option>
<option>Already a club member</option>
</select><br>
<br><label>Comments:</label><br>
<textarea id="comments" type="text" rows="5" cols="75"></textarea><br>
<br><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
<br><input type="reset">
</form>
</article>
</section>
<footer>
<p>Copyright - Oaktown Football Club</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function formValidation()
{
    var name = document.contactForm.fullName;
    var email = document.contactForm.email;
    var phone = document.contactForm.phone;
    var comment = document.contactForm.comment;

if (fullName.value == "") {
  alert("Please enter your name!");
  fullName.focus();
  return false;
}

if (email.value == "") {
  alert("Please enter your email address!");
  email.focus();
  return false;
}

if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
  alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
  email.focus();
  return false;
}

if (email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0) {
  alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
  email.focus();
  return false;
}

if (phone.value == "") {
  alert("Please enter your phone number!");
  phone.focus();
  return false;
}

if (phone.length < 2) {
  alert("Please enter a valid phone number!");
  phone.focus();
  return false;
}

if (comments.value == "") {
  alert("Please leave us a comment!");
  comments.focus();
  return false;
}
      {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: preventDefault() will help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you had stored the value of the '**Full Name**' in the variable 'name', but you were checking in your first '**if**' block, you were checking `if "fullName.value == ''".`

Thus, a '**Reference Error**' was being thrown.
After correcting it to `if "name.value == ''"`, the code works fine.

Please find below the working code in JSBin :-
http://jsbin.com/kemokijucu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Also, I noticed that you are checking the validity of an email address by simply checking if it contains a '.' and a '@' character.
However, with just these condition checks, I can even enter '..@@' as an email address and it is treated as valid!

Thus, a better way to check for a valid email address is using 'Regular Expressions'. You can use the below regular expression for emails :-

`/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

Comment: If the OP needs help with validating an email address, there are plenty of [*questions with answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+validate+email+address) already. ;-)

Comment: Yes, but it is highly likely that the OP wasn't aware that this was a potential caveat / pitfall in their code and so thought, it would be nice to bring it to notice, in case she wasn't already aware.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I will look at the regular expression for my email check as well. Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You get **name** :

```
var name = document.contactForm.fullName;
```

But check by **fullName** :

```
if (fullName.value == "") {
  alert("Please enter your name!");
  fullName.focus();
  return false;
}
```

Please up the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You have made mistake in fetching & using `name` element from the form. Below is the correction in JS.

```js
function formValidation() {

  var fullName = document.contactForm.name;
  var email = document.contactForm.email;
  var phone = document.contactForm.phone;
  var comment = document.contactForm.comment;

  if (fullName.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    fullName.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (email.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter your email address!");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
    alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0) {
    alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (phone.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter your phone number!");
    phone.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (phone.length < 2) {
    alert("Please enter a valid phone number!");
    phone.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (comments.value == "") {
    alert("Please leave us a comment!");
    comments.focus();
    return false;
  } {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>

  Oaktown Football Club</title>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Oaktown Football Club Logo" />
    <h1>Oaktown Football Club</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="Index.html">Homepage</a>
      <a href="Competitions.html">Competitions</a>
      <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <article>
      <h3>Secretary</h3>
      <p>Name: Laci Tanner</p>
      <p>Phone: (02) 6620 3324</p>
      <p>Email: <a href="mailto:secretary@oaktownfa.com.au">secretary@oaktownfa.com.au</a></p>
      <h3>Leave us a message</h3>
      <form method="post" action="actionPage.html" name="contactForm" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" size="35" name="fullName" id="name">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" size="35" name="email" id="email">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" size="35" name="phone" id="phone">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Team:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="team">
          <br>
          <option>Please Choose</option>
          <option>Adults</option>
          <option>Under 12s</option>
          <option>Under 6s</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>I am:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="Member">
          <br>
          <option>Please Choose</option>
          <option>Thinking about joining the club</option>
          <option>Already a club member</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Comments:</label>
        <br>
        <textarea id="comments" type="text" rows="5" cols="75"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="reset">
      </form>
    </article>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright - Oaktown Football Club</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Do try and debug the same using console in the browser.

You can change the type attribute of email field to `email` for auto email validation on the field.